# Openshift pipleline fails with error: # is already in progress (Running)

Tags: openshift, jenkins-pipeline

My openshift jenkins pipeline is failing at the last step while rolling out. 
Manual build in Openshift is working fine. It is creating the pods and terminating the others. Seams like when using pipeline , it was not able to terminate previous running pods.

when I terminated the running pod manually , then start pipe line it was working fine.

*However the similar pipe line is working fine on our test env.*

```
... previous stages

stage('PROD: Deploying image') {
              when {
                expression {
                  openshift.withCluster() {
                    openshift.withProject(PROD_PROJECTSPACE) {
                      return !openshift.selector('dc', "${APPLICATION_NAME}").exists()
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              steps {
                script {
                  openshift.withCluster() {
                    openshift.withProject(PROD_PROJECTSPACE) {
                      openshift.newApp("${APPLICATION_NAME}:latest --allow-missing-imagestream-tags").narrow('svc').expose("--port=3013");
                      def dc = openshift.selector("dc", "${APPLICATION_NAME}");
                        while (dc.object().spec.replicas != dc.object().status.availableReplicas) {
                          sleep 10
                        }
                        openshift.set("triggers", "dc/${APPLICATION_NAME}", "--manual")
                      }
                    }
                }
              }
            }

Failing in this stage

stage('PROD: Rollout') {
              steps {
                script {
                  openshift.withCluster() {
                    openshift.withProject(PROD_PROJECTSPACE) {
                      openshift.selector("dc", "${APPLICATION_NAME}").rollout().latest();
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
```

**Here is the error**

```
ERROR: rollout:latest returned an error;
{reference={}, err=error: #15 is already in progress (Running)., verb=rollout, cmd=oc --server=https://172.30.0.1:443 --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt --namespace=global-prod --token=XXXXX rollout latest deploymentconfig/global-events , out=, status=1}

Finished: FAILURE
```

**Could you point me something , any help would be helpful**

Comment: Created that pipeline using oc create -f myfile.yaml

Comment: Do you still have an ImageChange trigger defined in the DeploymentConfig? You need to remove that if triggering the deployment using a pipeline. If you don't, when the image builds, a new deployment will be automatically triggered by that, meaning that and Jenkins will both try and trigger a new deployment at the same time.

Comment: Did you mean this--- 
  triggers:
    - imageChangeParams:
        containerNames:
          - global-events
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: 'global-events:latest'
          namespace: global-test
        lastTriggeredImage: >-
          docker-registry.default.svc:5000/global-test/global-events@sha256:39f46ecd98b212d9afca2150821994d0d1dde970cd0a5be1ce096a854e206b9d
      type: ImageChange

Comment: Yes, run ``oc set triggers dc/yourappname --from-image --remove``.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in your comments. This can work, remove all triggers:

```
oc set triggers dc/${APPLICATION_NAME} --remove-all
```